# How to enable MPTCP on latest Android kernel?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-kernel, mptcp

I want to use mobile data and wifi interface simultaneously to increase data speed. I found that to achieve that we need to enable MPTCP at Android kernel level. There is good case study provided by Tessares.
I am finding a way to create latest system image (Android 10 at least) in which we can enable MPTCP.

Comment: Do you have source code for your device model?

Comment: No. I was thinking of downloading it from Android source tree and build stock rom for pixel device

Comment: so your answer is yes :)

Comment: if you ask open source for Android 10, then yes. I am exploring how to modify this code to enable mptcp.